# How to run local VM from golang?

Tags: go-ethereum, evm, golang, bytecode

I am going to run the virtual ethereum machine from the code, pass to it a compiled smart contract code.

But I do not know how to do it.

It's my code: 
package main

```
import (
    "context"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/vm"
)

func main() {
    var code string = "6060604052600a8060106000396000f360606040526008565b00"
    vm := vm.NewEVM(context.Background())

}
```

To create an instance of a virtual machine

> vm := vm.NewEVM()

I have to pass parameters such as:

```
- ctx Context 
- statedb StateDB
- chainConfig *params.ChainConfig
- vmConfig Config
```

Where to get these parameters?

Comment: Did you consider to use the "evm" utility of geth (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum)? It is mentioned in the README.md.
Once you install this utility you can run your code with the following command:
`evm --code 60ff60ff --debug`

Comment: Yes I know about it but I would just like to do the same from the  code.

I can not find anywhere how to do it.

Comment: Ah, ok. I think that the best place to get some insight about these data structures is the go ethereum code base itself. In particular I suggest you to take a look to the file `core/vm/evm.go`

Here you can find the definition of the struct context and understand what is needed.

Answer (score 2):

1) Context is created this way:

```
context := NewEVMContext(msg, header, bc, author)
```

Function definition is located in `core/evm.go`:

```
// NewEVMContext creates a new context for use in the EVM.
func NewEVMContext(msg Message, header *types.Header, chain ChainContext, author *common.Address) vm.Context {
```

2) You get StateDB like this:

```
statedb, err := blockchain.StateAt(block.Root())
if err != nil {
    log.Error("Can't get StateAt() , probably I am not running on a full node","block_num",block.Number().Uint64())
    return  err
}
```

Where `blockchain` is `core.Blockchain` object and `block` is a `types.Block` object

3) `ChainConfig` is created in params/config.go

```
MainnetChainConfig = &ChainConfig{
    ChainId:        big.NewInt(1),
    HomesteadBlock: big.NewInt(1150000),
    DAOForkBlock:   big.NewInt(1920000),
    DAOForkSupport: true,
    EIP150Block:    big.NewInt(2463000),
    EIP150Hash:     common.HexToHash("0x2086799aeebeae135c246c65021c82b4e15a2c451340993aacfd2751886514f0"),
    EIP155Block:    big.NewInt(2675000),
    EIP158Block:    big.NewInt(2675000),
    ByzantiumBlock: big.NewInt(4370000),

    Ethash: new(EthashConfig),
}
```

4) vm config is created like this:

```
    vm_cfg:=&vm.Config{
        Debug: false,
        EnableJit: false,
        ForceJit: false,
    }
```

Obviously , you have to import all these modules. Your `import` statement  will be something like this:

```
import(
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/consensus/misc"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/state"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/vm"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/log"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/params"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/utils"
}
```

The `cmd/evm` directory of Ethereum's `geth` distribution contains example code that you need to run an arbitrary EVM assembly.